# export_graphviz function, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, decision-tree, pygraphviz

Running a decision tree in python, all works perfectly except for exporting a graphic for the tree:

```
feature_cols = ['buildings_age','cell_id', 'pois:total', 'vertical_density',
                'Buildings:total', 'buildings_age:diversity',
                'ThirdPlaces:oa_count', 'pois:diversity', 'Roads:diversity',
                'Buildings:diversity']
X = data[feature_cols] # Features
y = data.most_present_age # Target variable
# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1) # 70% training and 30% test
# Create Decision Tree classifier object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini', max_depth=3)
# Train Decision Tree Classifier
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,  
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True,
                feature_names = feature_cols,class_names=[])
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
graph.write_png('tree.png')
Image(graph.create_png())
```

which gives the **error message**:

```
class_name = self.class_names[np.argmax(value)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is shown to come from the imported function export_graphviz
Class_name is ['0','1']
I'm pretty sure this is correct though so is the length of the feature_cols list to blame? or is it class name or something I haven't picked up on?
Any help would be **greatly appreciated, thank you**

Answer (score 0):

Your code has class names as an empty list: `class_names=[]` which shouldn't be the case. The class names should have names of each of the target classes in ascending numerical order. Only relevant for classification and not supported for multi-output.

You haven't shared a snippet of your target variable (most_present_age) but check the unique values in that column. Having age as a continuous variable, you can classify them into i.e age :

```
18-25 = 1
26-33 = 2
34-42 = 3
43-50 = 4
51-58 = 5
59-65 = 6
# etc
```

then you'll have your class names as `class_names = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']`
Your code should work.

Here's an example for your reference: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PhHMg7Tmn7LyWI64PH9NqCZkXqdV18HC#scrollTo=j4b-CHIBORol)